# How to delete python pkg_resources entry point?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I got a corrupted installation of mkdocs package on my computer that leaves me with 
`-kdocs` [entry point](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#entry-points) even after I unistall the mkdocs with pip.

```py
for theme in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group='mkdocs.themes'): print(theme.dist.key, theme)
-kdocs mkdocs = mkdocs.themes.mkdocs
-kdocs readthedocs = mkdocs.themes.readthedocs
```

I somehow ended up with a wierd package on my system:

```
a = [t for t in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group='mkdocs.themes')][0]
a.dist
Out[14]: -kdocs 1.0.4 (d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

but I cannot uninstall it with pip:

```
d:\github\mkdocs-material>pip uninstall "-kdocs"

Usage:
  pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: -k
```

The question: how to get rid of `-kdocs`?

Update:

Got even two ghosts:

```
d:\github\mkdocs-material>pip freeze > 1.txt
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -kdocs 1.0.4 (d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-kdocs=='": Expected W:(abcd...)
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -andas 0.25.3 (d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-andas=='": Expected W:(abcd...)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+dash+name

Answer (score 0):

Looki like I can fix by manually deleting `~kdocs` folder from from `d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`, but what creates this installation remains a mystery.